# What happened to Yukari Yukino in Kimi no Na wa?

Tags: your-name, garden-of-words

In the film *Kimi no Na wa. (Your Name.)*, a character from *Kotonoha no Niwa (The Garden of Words)* appeared as Miyamizu Mitsuha's literature teacher, that is, Yukari Yukino:

[image: Yukari Yukino in The Garden of Words]

[image: Yukari Yukino in Kimi no Na wa]

So the question is, as per the events that happened in Kimi no Na wa:

> A comet fell on Mitsuha's hometown, killing a third of the people.

Did Yukari Yukino die in those events?

Comment: I was wondering about the same... I guess she died there. Why? Because in the end of Kimi no wa, it is said that there were some casualties in the event. In the end of Kotonoha no niwa, the guy visits the place in the park where he usually meets Yukino and makes an altar and offers the pair of shoes as gift... and this is done for someone dead... So you can make your own conclusions with this two scenes. Or wach again and again the two films.

Comment: That's the problem with Makoto Shinkai works, they're all open-ended..

Comment: @Aogiri How exactly is Shinkai-san's works being open-ended a problem? :P.  I for one welcome the addition of titles that don't hand the reader/viewer a concrete resolution on a silver platter.

Comment: Problematic for questions like this. We can't have a concrete or official answer, unless the author says so.. All we can do is land on speculations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe Yuki-chan sensei (that's her name in the credits, ユキちゃん先生) died in the Itomori Accident. In the universe where Mitsuha had foreseen the disaster, she recruited the help of her friends, Teshigawara and Sayaka, to try to obviate casualties. Sayaka broadcasted to the townspeople to evacuate to Itomori High School, but was shortly stopped by the arriving school staff, which included Yuki-chan sensei.

[image: Yuki-chan sensei puts her hands on her chest at the sight of the comet splitting apart]

This means that Yuki-chan sensei was at or near the school, a place of safety, by around 7:42 pm, one hour before Comet Tiamat would strike. There is little sign that she would head to the festival place within one hour, as she was not dressed in yukata (most women were dressed in yukata at the festival). She would most likely stay for after-school duty for the remaining time.

And to refute [Anon's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/37221/what-happened-to-yukari-yukino-in-kimi-no-na-wa#comment50470_37221), in *Kotonoha no Niwa*, Yukino actually said at the start of September 2013 that she would go back to her hometown in Shikoku in a week. Moreover, she was later seen teaching a class in Shikoku, and even wrote a letter to Takao dated February 3, 2014. She was definitely not dead, and Takao didn't make any altar for Yukino. All these details entail that *Kimi no Na wa* and *Kotonoha no Niwa* couldn't possibly be set in the same universe, even though Yukari Yukino appeared in both movies.

Answer (score 1):

Spoiler alert.

If you have seen Garden of Words, in the novel that Makoto wrote after the movie, the two main characters met again after a few years in the same garden. The boy became a pro shoe maker and the teacher came back to Tokyo after a few years teaching, and I can assume that the city she was teaching then is the city in Kiwi no Na wa... So simple logic dictates that she didn't die.

Comment: In Kimi no Na wa, Yukino taught at Itomori High School, which I think is somewhere at or around Hida. This is neither Shigoku nor Tokyo (although Taki went to school in Tokyo), so I think you can't really reason she being alive in one film entails she would be alive in another. The times probably don't match either, as she was already seen teaching at Itomori at a date before she left Tokyo for another teaching position in Garden of Words.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you read Japanese one of the headlines for the "village didn't die" timeline was "0 killed, 109 injured". So nobody died in the timeline where Mitsuha survived.

Comment: That is a given. I think as the OP said "A comet fell on Mitsuha's hometown, killing a third of the people" he wants to know what happened to Yukari Yukino in the timeline where Mitsuha died.